# pandas memory usage when reindexing

Tags: python, memory, pandas

I wonder why `pandas` has a large memory usage when reindexing a Series.

I create a simple dataset:

```
a = pd.Series(np.arange(5e7, dtype=np.double))
```

According to `top` on my Ubuntu, the whole session is about 820MB.

Now if I slice this to extract the first 100 elements:

```
a_sliced = a[:100]
```

This shows no increased memory consumption.

Instead if I reindex `a` on the same range:

```
a_reindexed = a.reindex(np.arange(100))
```

I get a memory consumption of about 1.8GB. Tried also to cleanup with `gc.collect` without success.

I would like to know if this is expected and if there is a workaround to reindex large datasets without significant memory overhead.

I am using a very recent snapshot of `pandas` from github.

Comment: `reindex` will be default create a copy, so if the old variable is still around you should get about double the memory usage. Have you tried passing `copy=False` to `reindex`?

Comment: thanks, tried with `copy=False`, but nothing changes. Also, I thought `pandas` created a copy of the reindexed data, not of the complete original dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index uses a Hashtable to map labels to locations. You can check this by `Series.index._engine.mapping`. This mapping is created when necessary. If the index `is_monotonic`, you can use `asof()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
idx =["%07d" % x for x in range(int(2e6))]
a = pd.Series(np.arange(2e6, dtype=np.double), index=idx)
new_index = ["0000003", "0000020", "000002a"]

print a.index._engine.mapping # None
print a.reindex(new_index)
print a.index._engine.mapping # <pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable object at ...>

a = pd.Series(np.arange(2e6, dtype=np.double), index=idx)
print a.asof(new_index)
print a.index._engine.mapping # None
```

If you want more control about not exist labels, you can use `searchsorted()` and do the logic yourself:

```
>>> a.index[a.index.searchsorted(new_index)] 
Index([u'0000003', u'0000020', u'0000030'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Be very very careful setting `copy=False` FYI. This can cause some weird effects. Copying the index is 'cheap' if your data is large relative to the index size (which looks like it is).

If you want to eliminate the memory associated after reindexing, do something like this:

```
s = a_big_series
s2 = s.reindex(....)
```

Memory is still used because the underlying data is just a view of the old data (dependening on how you are slicing it. It could be copy, but this is numpy dependent).

```
s2 = s.reindex(....).copy()
del s
```

This will release the memory

Comment: HYRY's comment below is the issue -- the reindex is creating a large hash table that isn't being garbage collected unless you take the approach you listed. We should add a method to pandas that deletes all hash tables. Or something.