# Pandas: Why is Series indexing using .loc taking 100x longer on the first run when timing it?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time, timeit

I'm slicing a quite big pandas series (~5M) using .loc and I stumble upon some weird behavior when checking times in an attempt to optimize my code.

It's weird that the first slicing attempt like `series_object.loc[some_indexes]` is taking 100x longer than the following ones.

When I try `timeit` it does not reflect this behaviour, but when checking the partial laps using `time``, we can see that the first lap is taking much longer than the following ones.

1. Is `.loc` using some sort of cacheing? if that's so, how does garbage collection is not influencing this?
2. Is `timeit` doing the cacheing even with garbage collector disabled and not behaving as it's suppose?
3. Which time should I trust that my app in production will take when running in a live environment?

I tried this on `windows` and `linux` machines using different versions of `python (3.6, 3.7 and 2.7)` and the behavior is always the same.

Thanks in advance for you help. This thing is banging my head for a week already and I miss not doubting `%timeit` :)

**to reproduce:**

**Save the following code to a python file eg.:`test_loc_times.py`**

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import timeit
    import time, gc

    def get_data():
        ids = np.arange(size_bigseries)
        big_series = pd.Series(index=ids, data=np.random.rand(len(ids)), name='{} elements series'.format(len(ids)))
        small_slice = np.arange(size_slice)
        return big_series, small_slice

    # Method to test: a simple pandas slicing with .loc
    def basic_loc_indexing(pd_series, slice_ids):
        return pd_series.loc[slice_ids].dropna()

    # method to time it
    def timing_it(func, n, *args):
        gcold = gc.isenabled()
        gc.disable()
        times = []
        for i in range(n):
            s = time.time()
            func(*args)
            times.append((time.time()-s)*1000)

        if gcold:
            gc.enable()

        return times

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        n_tries = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv)>1 and sys.argv[1] is not None else 1000
        size_bigseries = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv)>2 and sys.argv[2] is not None else 5000000 #5M
        size_slice =  int(sys.argv[3]) if  len(sys.argv)>3 and sys.argv[3] is not None else 100 #5M
        #1: timeit()
        big_series, small_slice = get_data()
        time_with_timeit = timeit.timeit('basic_loc_indexing(big_series, small_slice)',"gc.disable(); from __main__ import basic_loc_indexing, big_series, small_slice",number=n_tries)
        print("using timeit: {:.6f}ms".format(time_with_timeit/n_tries*1000))
        del big_series, small_slice

        #2: time()
        big_series, small_slice = get_data()
        time_with_time = timing_it(basic_loc_indexing, n_tries, big_series, small_slice)
        print("using time: {:.6f}ms".format(np.mean(time_with_time)))
        print('head detail: {}\n'.format(time_with_time[:5]))
```

**try out:**

Run

```sh
python test_loc_times.py 1000 5000000 100
```

This will run `timeit` and `time` `1000` laps on slicing `100` elements from a `5M` pandas.Series.

you can try it yourself with other values and the first run it always taking longer.

**stdout:**

```
>>> using timeit: 0.789754ms
>>> using time: 0.829869ms
>>> head detail: [145.02716064453125, 0.7691383361816406, 0.7028579711914062, 0.5738735198974609, 0.6380081176757812]
```

Weird right?

## edit:

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18074101/3065498) which might be related. What do you think?

Comment: If runing only once:
```python test_loc.py 1 500000 100

using timeit: 14.925658ms

using time: 16.806841ms

head detail: [16.806840896606445]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is likely not idempotent (has side effects that impact its execution).

`timeit` will run the code once first to measure the time and deduce the number of loops and runs it should use. If your code is not idempotent (has side effects, like cashing) then that first run (not recorded) will be longer and the subsequent (faster runs) will be measured and reported.

You can take a look at the arguments you can pass to `timeit` ([see the doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit)) to specify the number of loops and forgo that initial run.

Also note that (taken from the doc linked above):

> The times reported by %timeit will be slightly higher than those reported by the timeit.py script when variables are accessed. This is due to the fact that %timeit executes the statement in the namespace of the shell, compared with timeit.py, which uses a single setup statement to import function or create variables. Generally, the bias does not matter as long as results from timeit.py are not mixed with those from %timeit.

**Edit:** Missed the fact that you were passing the number of runs to timeit. In that case, only the latter part of my answer applies, but the numbers you are seeing seem to point to another issue...

Comment: the code is specifying the number of runs to run `timeit()`.

Comment: do you want to hypothesize why is `.loc` taking longer in the first lap?

Comment: I don't think `timeit` is central to the question asked here. Both with and without using `timeit`, the displayed behaviour is that the first iteration takes longer than the ones after that. Why?